# Is it possible to connect a Raspberry Pi with multiple inertial sensors simultaneously via Bluetooth?

Tags: bluetooth, arduino

I'm working on a project in which I have to connect 3 (or more) inertial sensors to a virtual reality headset (OculusQuest) via Bluetooth, but the problem is that it only accepts one connection, so I would need some intermediate step to join the data of the sensors in one device and send them from this device to the virtual reality headset. At first, I thought of using an Arduino, but it seems most Bluetooth modules only accept one connection, so it's not possible to have 4 slaves at the same time (the 3 sensors and the virtual reality headset) in an easy way, so I thought of using a Raspberry Pi.

What I would need is to connect the Raspberry Pi to 4 devices via Bluetooth simultaneously: the 3 inertial sensors (which would send the data simultaneously to the Raspberry Pi) and the virtual headset (which would receive the data from the Raspberry Pi). Is this possible to do with some Raspberry Pi model?

Thank you.

Comment: There are several versions of Raspberry Pi and the Bluetooth hardware version differ between them so which one do you have ? And the number of simultaneously is depending on the Bluetooth Hardware version.

Comment: @MatsKarlsson I still don't have one. I'm researching the version I need to connect at least those 4 devices simultaneously before getting one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bluetooth 4.0 can have 7 simultaneous connection. More recent versions can have more device connections, but that's another question.

And the lowest level any Raspberry Pi have built in is Bluetooth ver 4.2.

You can find detailed info about various Raspberry Pi versions here https://www.raspberrypi.org/products/

**Note:** There are some BLE chips that have hardware limitations.

Ref. Answer by Tim Tisdall, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21154919/how-many-devices-we-can-pair-via-bluetooth-of-ble-to-android

Comment: thank you very much. And what do you mean by hardware limitations?

Comment: I have read a couple of years ago, and I tried to find the article again without luck. And it's one thing what the specification say and another what hardware/software deliver. So I can remove that "Note" until i find the url again.